# Op-amp comparator 0 V - +5 V outputting +1 V - +5 V PWM

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm

I am trying to make a PWM signal for controlling a motor.

The [TL082](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082-n.pdf) op-amp, connected between 0 and +5 V, takes

- a triangular input generated by an astable and filtered by a capacitor on the (-) input
- an adjustable voltage, made by a R/2R resistor network on the (+) input

All this works at about 50 kHz. In theory, the output should vary from 0 to +5 V, but in reality, it varies from +1.4 V to +5 V.

I tried to add a pull-down resistor (1 kΩ and 10 kΩ), I also tried a pull up (never know) without results. I also tried a feedback loop with a 1 kΩ resistor on the (-) which changed nothing. I lowered the frequency to 25 kHz, which changed nothing. I know that these were useless, but I was not able to come up with tomething else, this is a REALLY basic circuit.

Here is the diagram:

[image: Electric diagram]

and here are the oscilloscope traces:

The triangle input and the adjustable one (random value):

[image: Triangle and adjustable input]

The triangle input and the output depending on the adjustable input level:

[image: Triangle input and output]

I must be wrong somewhere, but I don't get where; normally in comparator mode, the outputs are between V- and V+ and that's it. Maybe it is the fact that I use it between 0 V and +5 V?

On the other hand, the PWM is working, it changes  with the adjustable voltage increase.

Comment: What exactly is an AOP?

Comment: TL082 is not a rail-to-rail opamp. You need a rail-to-rail opamp, or a dual supply if you must use this one.

Comment: @Hearth: an AOP is a French op-amp. Edited it.

Comment: Your measurements appear to be taken with a Fluke/Philips combiscope, yes? (Just curious.)

Comment: @Hearth Yes, it is an Op amp in french, sorry :)

Comment: @Adam Lawrence The scope is a Hitachi V1565, I had it for 50€ ^^,

Comment: Very nice! Congrats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A TL082 is an op amp, and is not designed to be used as a comparator. Its internal circuitry is optimized for *linear* operation in feedback, and isn't optimized for the kinds of saturation that occur with large-signal effects in a comparator.

Moreover, this is not a "rail to rail IO" op amp, and its output driver cannot reach all the way down to 0 V or all the way up to 5 V. In the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl082-n.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-alldatasheets-df-pf-SEP-wwe) you can see that the output stage has a fairly straightforward push-pull as its final stage:

[image]

This structure encounters Vbe drops on both its PNP and NPN output transistors, which means that the best output range you can expect is around 0.7 - 4.3 V (assuming the prior stage can reach a wide enough range).

Use a comparator instead (and if it has an open-collector/open-drain output, add a pullup resistor). The [LM393](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf) conveniently has the same pinout and an open collector output, requiring only the addition of the pull-up resistor. It's also faster - it slews from 0 to 5 V in 0.25 microseconds (20 V/μs), while the TL081 only slews at 13 V/μs. Aside from that, it's a fairly old and simple comparator, and you can get even faster/more advanced ones to meet specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there a component you would recommand?

Comment: @zepeu LM393. I'm finishing up an edit very soon.

Comment: Perfect, the LM393 seems to be the basic and very useful one, thank you a lot :)

Comment: @zepeu Not a problem, happy to help.